# jquery - function on boostrap button doesnt execute at first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a problem

I have this jquery function

```js
$("#toggle").click(function(){ 
  
  if($("#toggle").attr("aria-pressed") == "true"){
    $("button[data-toggle='button']").attr("aria-pressed","true");
    $("button[data-toggle='button']").attr("class","btn btn-outline-dark focus active");
  }else{
   $("button[data-toggle='button']").attr("aria-pressed","false");
   $("button[data-toggle='button']").attr("class","btn btn-outline-dark");

  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" aria-pressed="false" data-toggle="button" id="toggle">Toggle</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" >Comp</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" >Comp</button>
```

Problem is that toggle button fuction doesnt execute after first click , but on 2nd click it works like it should. Can somebody explain me why? Basically i want to set  those 2 buttons "Comp" active and again deactive by clicking on Toggle.

Comment: your toggle button doesn't have the "aria-pressed" attribute on load so the first click fails

Comment: already added it, but still it doesnt work

Comment: If you want them to be toggled on, on the first click it needs to be `aria-pressed="true"` not `aria-pressed="false"`

Comment: it should be aria-pressed="true" also side not : use === in your jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the attribute  to your html for toggle button like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="button" id="toggle" aria-pressed="true">Toggle</button>
```

here is a working jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/vdadekvL/26/

Answer (score 1):

There was a few issues,

**1)** The attribute `aria-pressed` was not defined on the first click, so you have to detect it.

**2)** The "good" way of adding/removing class is using `addClass()` or `removeClass()`. Even more, you can use `toggleClass()`.

```js
$("#toggle").click(function()
{
    if (!$(this).attr("aria-pressed") || $(this).attr("aria-pressed") == "true")
    {
        $("button[data-toggle='button']").attr("aria-pressed","true");
        $("button[data-toggle='button']").addClass("focus active");
    }
    else
    {
        $("button[data-toggle='button']").attr("aria-pressed","false");
        $("button[data-toggle='button']").removeClass("focus active");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="button" id="toggle">Toggle</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" >Comp</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off" >Comp</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the .on event handler instead of .click - it's good practice as it handles dynamically added elements.

In my example below this listens for DOM change events on the body level.

**Doc:** http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("body").on("click","#toggle",function(){  
// your code here
});
```

Another thing to consider is that since you are setting the button to "false" on first click, you'll never get into the "true" case on any subsequent clicks.

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/zdvonpr2/